# Tree-style sidebar in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have been looking around, and it seems that the sidebar format is a built-in to beamer. How might I go about changing the formatting so that it can be represented as a [`tree`-like output](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/)?

EDIT: MWE below:

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Singapore}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{frame}
First frame without title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\begin{frame}
Second frame without title.
\end{frame}
\section{Section2}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\begin{frame}
Third frame without title.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Subsection2}
\begin{frame}
Fourth frame without title.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This does two things perfectly - it displays all of the headings and subheadings on the side of every slide. It also puts the current one as bold.

A couple of problems arise though. First, it only shows sections and subsections (not subsubsections). Second, it doesn't have the bars on the left hand side to create the tree. I've also seen a tree-type, but on top of the slides [as like here](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~frank/ENG/beamer/example/beamer-class-example-en-8-Montpellier.html). Here's what I am trying to get on the sidebar:

```
├── blank
│   ├── defaults
│   ├── files
│   ├── handlers
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── meta
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── tasks
│   ├── templates
│   └── vars
└── Blank
    ├── ansible.cfg
    ├── dev
    │   ├── group_vars
    │   │   └── all
    │   └── hosts
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── plays
    ├── prod
    │   ├── group_vars
    │   │   └── all
    │   └── hosts
    ├── README.md
    ├── requirements.yml
    ├── roles
    │   ├── external
    │   └── internal
    │       └── blank
    └── site.yml
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a Minimal Working Example in the form of code we can compile. Beamer offers a number of themes and templates, including sidebars and tree-style navigation. None of these is used by default. So I'm not sure what you mean: sidebars of various kinds are available, so they are `built-in` in that sense, but so are tree-alike navigation styles.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% total number of sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{totalsection}
\regtotcounter{totalsection}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pretocmd{\section}{\refstepcounter{totalsection}}{}{}%
}%

% number of subsections per section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterCounters{section}{subsection}
\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\setcounter{totalsubsection}{0}

% creating automatic label %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386557/36296
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{\label{subsec:\thesection:\thesubsection}}
\newcounter{currentsub}
\newcounter{totsection}

% Creating the sidebar
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,left,width=.22\textwidth]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!20!white}

\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=alerted text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=structure}

\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=alerted text.fg!30!bg}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg=structure}
\setbeamercolor{current subsection in sidebar}{fg=alerted text.fg}


\usepackage{pgffor}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\beamer@sidebarwidth,sep=2em]{sidebar}%
        \usebeamerfont{section in sidebar}%
        %
        % parent = title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \insertshorttitle\newline%
        %
        % first level = section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\totvalue{totalsection}}{%
            % get number of subsections in current section
            \setcounter{currentsub}{\ObtainTrackedValueExp[\i]{section}{subsection}}%
            % insert vertical line + line to right |-
            \ifnum\i=\totvalue{totalsection}%
                \textSFii%
            \else% shorter line for final section
                \textSFviii%
            \fi%
            % insert horzonal line - or T if there are subsection
            \ifnum\thecurrentsub>0%
                \textSFvi%
            \else%
                \textSFx%
            \fi%
            % insert hoziontal line -
            \textSFx~%
            % insert hyperline to section
            {%
                \ifnum\i=\value{section}%
                    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar}%
                \else%
                    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section in sidebar shaded}%
                \fi%
                \mbox{\hyperlink{sec:\i}{\nameref{sec:\i}}}\newline%
            }%
            %
            %   secon level = subsection %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            \ifnum\thecurrentsub>0%
                \foreach \j in {1,...,\thecurrentsub}{%
                    % vertical line to connect section | 
                    \ifnum\i<\totvalue{totalsection}%
                        \textSFxi%
                    \else%
                        \textcolor{bg}{\textSFxi}% not for the last section
                    \fi%
                    % 
                    % insert vertical line + line to right |-
                    \ifnum\j=\thecurrentsub%
                        \textSFii%
                \else% shorter line for final section
                    \textSFviii%
                \fi%
                % insert hoziontal line -
                \textSFx\textSFx~%
                % insert hyperline to section
                {%
                    \ifnum\i=\value{section}%
                        \ifnum\j=\value{subsection}%
                            \usebeamercolor[fg]{current subsection in sidebar}%
                        \else%
                            \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar}%
                        \fi%
                    \else%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection in sidebar shaded}%
                    \fi%
                    \mbox{\hyperlink{subsec:\i:\j}{\nameref{subsec:\i:\j}}}\newline%
                }%
            }%
        \fi%        
        }%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother

\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\section{Section One}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Two}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection a}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection b}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection c}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Three}
\frame{abc} 

\section{Section Three}
\frame{abc} 

\subsection{subsection a}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection b}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection c}
\frame{abc}        

\end{document}
```

[image]