# Beamer button link to Section page

Tags: beamer, links

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{sec:hula}{\beamerbutton{Jump}}
\end{frame}

\section{Test 2}\label{sec:hula}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The `Jump` button links to the page 4 (where the section starts), but 
I want it will link to page 3 (the Section ToC page). How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not tested... but if doesn't work I suppose you can play with such kind of "
"trick"

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcounter{sectionTOC}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \stepcounter{sectionTOC}
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \ifnum\thesectionTOC=2
    \label{sec:hula}
    \fi
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{sec:hula}{\beamerbutton{Jump}}
\end{frame}

\section{Test 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use it multiple times a more automatic way is to not use \thesection counter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}


\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \label{sec:\thesection}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlink{sec:2}{\beamerbutton{Jump}}
\end{frame}

\section{Test 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

(Tested)

Comment: Accepted the 2nd solution

Answer (score 3):

For the special case shown in your MWE where you want to link to the start of the next section, you can use `\hyperlinksectionstartnext`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame}
\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerbutton{this section}}
\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerbutton{next section}}
\end{frame}

\section{Test 2}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 because it is more forward for the specific problem than mine... I think both of our solutions will be useful for future readers.

Comment: @koleygr I already voted your answer as it could actually solve a problem I had for years with links in a mindmap used as table of contents :)