# Set beamer section numbers opposite the first line of the title

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, beamer-metropolis

I want my section page number be on the first line of the section name, like this.
[image]
How can i do this?

My document code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=43]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\newcounter{sectionpage}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
    \setcounter{sectionpage}{\insertframenumber}\stepcounter{sectionpage}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2\hfill\thesectionpage}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{\LARGE{TOC}}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could position the page number in a separate cell of a table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\LARGE}
    \frametitle{TOC}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
        \insertsectionhead & \insertsectionstartpage\\  
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name}

\end{document}
```

---

Or a bit more complicate with subsections

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% total number of sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{totalsection}
\regtotcounter{totalsection}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pretocmd{\section}{\refstepcounter{totalsection}}{}{}%
}%

% number of subsections per section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterCounters{section}{subsection}
\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\setcounter{totalsubsection}{0}

% creating automatic label %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386557/36296
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{\label{subsec:\thesection:\thesubsection}}
\newcounter{currentsub}
\newcounter{totsection}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\LARGE}
        \setcounter{currentsub}{\ObtainTrackedValueExp[\thesection]{section}{subsection}}
    \frametitle{TOC}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
        \insertsectionhead & \insertsectionstartpage\\  
    \end{tabularx}
    \ifnum\thecurrentsub>0%
            \foreach \j in {1,...,\thecurrentsub}{%
                \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X r}
                    \nameref{subsec:\thesection:\j} & \pageref{subsec:\thesection:\j}\\
                \end{tabularx}
            }
        \fi
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name Section name}

\subsection{sub1}
\begin{frame}
sub1
\end{frame}

\subsection{sub2}
\begin{frame}
sub2
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]