# How can I format the beamer \tableofcontents in a non-list style smarter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I currently have a use case, where a set of graphically fancy table of contents slides have been created for PowerPoint and I want to copy the design for LaTeX beamer while preserving the capability to automatically fill the current content that would normally be ejected through `\tableofcontents` into a `tikzpicture` instead of the normal list environment. Preferably I want to do this without the requirement of dual compilation (through fixed anchors and `remember picture,overlay`.

So here is what I want to achieve finally:
[image]

Of course the original is more appealing. ;-)

Here is the current version showing the static code (that would prevent the double compilation), that produces the fancy ToC, but not automatically and then also the change of the `section in toc` template, which requires dual compilation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{bubble/.style={circle,text width=2cm,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{
    \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount=1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[green] ($(current page.south west) + (1cm,1cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east) - (1cm,1cm)$);
        \node(first)[bubble,fill=red] at ($(current page.south west) + (2.4cm,2.5cm)$) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
    \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount=2
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node(second)[bubble,fill=orange] at ($(current page.south west) + (4.5cm,7.2cm)$) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
        \draw (first) -- (second);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
    \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount=3
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node(third)[bubble,fill=magenta] at ($(current page.south west) + (6cm,3cm)$) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
    \draw (second) -- (third);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
    \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount=4
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node(fourth)[bubble,fill=pink] at ($(current page.south west) + (8cm,7cm)$) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
    \draw (third) -- (fourth);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
    \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount=5
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node(fifth)[bubble,fill=cyan] at ($(current page.south west) + (10cm,3cm)$) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
    \draw (fourth) -- (fifth);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \fi
    \,%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle ++(\textwidth,0.85\textheight);
    \node(first)[bubble,fill=red] at (0.15\textwidth,0.15\textheight) {01\\First Chapter};
    \node(second)[bubble,fill=orange] at (0.3\textwidth,0.7\textheight) {02\\Second Chapter};
    \node(third)[bubble,fill=magenta] at (0.45\textwidth,0.3\textheight) {03\\Third Chapter};
    \node(fourth)[bubble,fill=pink] at (0.7\textwidth,0.7\textheight) {04\\Fourth Chapter};
    \node(fifth)[bubble,fill=cyan] at (0.8\textwidth,0.2\textheight) {05\\Fifth Chapter};
    \draw (first) -- (second) -- (third) -- (fourth) -- (fifth);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{First Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Second Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Third Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Fourth Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Fifth Chapter}
\frame{Test}

\end{document}
```

---

I experimented a bit with patching the `\tableofcontents`, but I still cannot find a way to not compile twice, as this is required by the referencing of nodes in another `tikzpicture`:

```
\colorlet{bubbleColor}{green}
\tikzset{bubble/.style={circle,fill=bubbleColor,text width=2cm,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}

\usepackage{etoolbox,xfp}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle ++(\textwidth,0.85\textheight);
    \coordinate(section1) at (0.15\textwidth,0.15\textheight);
    \coordinate(section2) at (0.3\textwidth,0.7\textheight);
    \coordinate(section3) at (0.45\textwidth,0.3\textheight);
    \coordinate(section4) at (0.7\textwidth,0.7\textheight);
    \coordinate(section5) at (0.8\textwidth,0.2\textheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\tableofcontents}{}{}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{
    \ifodd\the\beamer@tempcount
        \colorlet{bubbleColor}{red}
    \else
        \colorlet{bubbleColor}{magenta}
    \fi
    \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount=1
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node(section\inserttocsectionnumber)[bubble] at (section\inserttocsectionnumber) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \else
        \ifnum\the\beamer@tempcount<6
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node(section\inserttocsectionnumber)[bubble] at (section\inserttocsectionnumber) {0\inserttocsectionnumber\\ \inserttocsection};
            \draw (section\inteval{\inserttocsectionnumber - 1}) -- (section\inserttocsectionnumber);
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \fi
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You'll always have to compile twice when dealing with the toc. At the start of the document, latex can't know what the sections will be and needs the first run to collect them.

Comment: Sure, but that is for the content of the ToC. But will the way I introduced also have the anchors in place for the first compilation run? I will check that because I didn't thought about your true comment. I was only focussing on the TikZ part.

Comment: I just checked it and the way I constructed it indeed requires three runs. In the first run only the background is shown, in the second run the items are drawn, but at random locations and this is only corrected in the third run. So if it would be possible to draw the TikZ image in a way that it is there with the second run, I'd be happy!

Comment: If you want the tikz image on the second run, don't use `remember picture` and `overlay`. Instead use a single tikz picture and  absolute coordinates. You could move your toc into a separate command and loop yourself over the sections, see e.g. this answer https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1987#a2230

Comment: Well Sam, this is what I am asking for in my question. ;-)
I had a look on the link and will build upon that, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is now instead of manipulating the `\tableofcontents` command or fiddling around with reading the `TOC`-file first to just define my own commands and then read in the `TOC`-file. Here it is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\colorlet{bubbleColor}{orange}
\tikzset{bubble/.style={circle,fill=bubbleColor,text width=1.5cm,align=center,inner sep=2pt,font=\small}}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\let\beameroriginal@sectionintoc\beamer@sectionintoc

%%%%\def\beamer@endinputifotherversion#1{}
\renewcommand{\beamer@sectionintoc}[5]{ \ifodd#1%
    \colorlet{bubbleColor}{red}%
    \else%
    \colorlet{bubbleColor}{magenta}%
    \fi%
    \node(bubble#1)[bubble] at (section#1) {#2};}
%%%%\def\beamer@subsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6{}
%%%%\def\beamer@subsubsectionintoc#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{}

\frame{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle ++(\textwidth,0.85\textheight);
    \coordinate(section1) at (0.15\textwidth,0.15\textheight);
    \coordinate(section2) at (0.3\textwidth,0.7\textheight);
    \coordinate(section3) at (0.45\textwidth,0.3\textheight);
    \coordinate(section4) at (0.7\textwidth,0.7\textheight);
    \coordinate(section5) at (0.8\textwidth,0.2\textheight);
    \@input{\jobname.toc}
    \draw (bubble1) -- (bubble2) -- (bubble3) -- (bubble4) -- (bubble5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\let\beamer@sectionintoc\beameroriginal@sectionintoc
\makeatother

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{First Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Second Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Third Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Fourth Chapter}
\frame{Test}
\section{Fifth Chapter}
\frame{Test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1987#a2230

The first run will through an error, but you could add some exception handling. On the second run, the tikz picture should be there

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,shadows}

% total number of sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{totalsection}
\regtotcounter{totalsection}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \pretocmd{\section}{\refstepcounter{totalsection}}{}{}%
}%

% number of subsections per section %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn % fix xcntperchap
\cs_set_eq:NN \c_zero \c_zero_int
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{xcntperchap}
\RegisterCounters{section}{subsection}
\newcounter{totalsubsection}
\setcounter{totalsubsection}{0}

% creating automatic label %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386557/36296
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{\label{subsec:\thesection:\thesubsection}}
\newcounter{currentsub}
\newcounter{totsection}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{bubble/.style={circle,text width=2cm,align=center,inner sep=2pt}}

\newcounter{foo}

\newcommand{\mindtoc}{%
    \centering
    \setcounter{totsection}{\number\totvalue{totalsection}}
       \begin{tikzpicture}
          \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle ++(\textwidth,0.85\textheight);
          \coordinate(section1) at (0.15\textwidth,0.15\textheight);
          \coordinate(section2) at (0.3\textwidth,0.7\textheight);
          \coordinate(section3) at (0.45\textwidth,0.3\textheight);
          \coordinate(section4) at (0.7\textwidth,0.7\textheight);
          \coordinate(section5) at (0.8\textwidth,0.2\textheight);
        \foreach \mysec in {1,...,\thetotsection}{%   
          \setcounter{foo}{\mysec}
          \addtocounter{foo}{1}
          \ifnum\thetotsection<\thefoo
          \else
            \draw (section\thefoo) -- (section\mysec);
          \fi
          \ifodd\mysec
              \colorlet{bubbleColor}{red}
          \else
              \colorlet{bubbleColor}{magenta}
          \fi
          \node[circle,fill=bubbleColor,text width=2cm,align=center,inner sep=2pt] at (section\mysec) {
            \mysec\\
            \hyperlink{sec:\mysec}{\nameref{sec:\mysec}}
            };
%       };
       } 
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

% \tracingall
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{"Table" of Contents}
    \mindtoc    
\end{frame}

\section{Section One}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Two}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection a}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection b}
\frame{abc}

\subsection{subsection c}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Three}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Four}
\frame{abc}

\end{document}
```