# Graphic tree-like symbols in text

Tags: tables, indentation

Just dont know how to properly form the question... perhaps it's easiest to show it in a picture..

I have a simple table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & Test1 \\
2 & \hspace{5mm}Test2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

and what I would like to get is something like this:

[image]

Is there an easy way of getting this kind of line in text ... ?

Thank you,
A.

Comment: Maybe you can get some inspiration from this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436246/134144

Comment: Or look at the `dirtree` package.

Comment: The `pmboxdraw` could be useful. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355420/tree-style-sidebar-in-beamer/415963#415963 for an example how to create a tree with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain that just playing with `amssymb`. I simply defined a `\treesym` command-symbol made up of `\llcorner`  and `\relbar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\treesym}{\ensuremath{\mkern 12mu\raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{$ \llcorner $}\mkern-5mu{\relbar}}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & Test1 \\
2 & \treesym Test2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have used instead of the Bernard's answer `\usepackage{graphicx}+$\mkern 14mu\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1.5}[-2]{$\neg$}}$` for the tree-like symbols in text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & Test1 \\
2 & $\mkern 14mu\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1.5}[-2]{$\neg$}}$ Test2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```